# Php Auto increment on rows continuously by page

Tags: php, auto-increment, paging

Hi i have this problem with my web page, I was able to solve the issue on auto-increment of a row but then another issue struck me. When I go to another page, the auto-increment resets and didn't[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfisu.png) continue with the last number. Hope you could help

[the output on page 1 and last page which the number didn't continue to count[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZSQA.png)

Comment: THIS IS MY CODE:

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  What "auto-increment"?  Do you have a database table with an auto-incrementing ID?  How is it "resetting"?  How are you "paging"?  Please show the code you're using and explain the problem.

Comment: Are you asking about the number that shows next to each user on the UI?

Comment: Code should not be an image of it, but as actual code.

Comment: Yes sir i am referring to the numbers next to the user because i need to have that number ordered till to the last page

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screen-shot, I can see that the page number is included as a parameter in the URL. You can use this parameter to offset your counter.

```
$i = $_GET['page_no'] * $people_per_page + 1;
```

Comment: thanks sir for your answer but then do i need to create another variable for that people per page?

Comment: You can, or you can just insert it straight into the code as a constant. I would make it a variable so that it's easy to find and change if you ever modify your design in the future.

Comment: You may also have to double check if `$_GET['page_no']` exists if it isn't explicitly included on the first page. Also, this assumes that you start from page 0, you'll have to subtract 1 from the page number if you start at 1 (keep order of operations in mind if you do)

Comment: $i=1;
   while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {

Comment: thats my code on the retrieving sir so ill change that declaration of variable i to the code that you gave?

Comment: it seems that i am getting errors sir. because i am using classes and the paging code is at the bottom. on different functions

Comment: Add a parameter to your `dataview` function that accepts the initial number. Calculate `$i` like I showed you on the actual page, and pass that number to `dataview`.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CtVMxSd_0IkbFubWneCgXbTZnbkn1rqn?usp=sharing

Comment: sir would you mind checking my code on the google drive? and rechek it for me? that would be a great help sir! thanks!

Comment: because i dont have any idea onto how to do it sir. im new in php objects